# Using Laravel 5 Encryption on multiple projects

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7, laravel-5.5

Basically I have two Laravel applications (5.5 & 5.4).

My question is: Can I use Laravel Encryption to **"encrypt"** it in my first project and **"decrypt"** it on my second project?

I am aware that **Laravel Encryption** use a **key** option in your config/app.php to generate the encryption. I'm just asking if there's a valid way to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As long as you use the same `APP_KEY` in both.env files, it will work

Comment: Plus set too same encryption type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no backward incompatible changes in Laravel Encryption code between versions 5.4 and 5.5 ([release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/releases)) so as long as you use the same `APP_KEY` and the same encryption algorithm you will be able to decrypt data across your apps.

Comment: So it is safe to change the APP_KEY manually rather than running it with "php artisan key:generate"?

Comment: Sure. artisan just generates random string for you but it's safe to use own or generate by other means

Comment: Okay I'll take note on that. :) Thanks!

Comment: See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L68